# VB.NET Connect to MySQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm using the following code to connect to a MySQL database hosted with GoDaddy. According to multiple references, this *should* work, but I get the error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

Im wondering if I've configured something wrong as the words *Local Server* suggest that its not attempting to connect to the server at all?

Code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Module Licence_Check

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

    Public Sub ConnectToDatabase()

        Dim DatabaseName As String = "ALVEAREKEYSCHK"

        Dim server As String = "XXXX.db.XXXXXX.hostedXXXXX.com"

        Dim userName As String = "ALVEAREKEYSCHK"

        Dim password As String = "SXXXXXXXXXX!"

        If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()

        conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)

        Try

            conn.Open()



            MsgBox("Connected")

        Catch ex As Exception

            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

        conn.Close()


    End Sub

End Module
```

*Some things have been replaced with X's*

**UPDATE 1**

In response to the answers, I've updated the code to:

```
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=SERVERNAMEHERE;uid=USERIDHERE;pwd=PASSWORDHERE;database=DATABASEHERE;")
    Try
        conn.Open()
        MsgBox("connection open")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Something seems to have changed as now I'm getting the following error:

> '`SERVERNAMEHERE`' for user
>   '`USERIDISHERE`' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed
>   with message: Access denied for user '`USERIDISHERE`'
>   (using password: YES)

I'm guessing this is a server side issue now? Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Do you need to specify the port to connect?

Comment: I've tried specifying the port, but it makes no difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=host;uid=db_id;pwd=db_password;database=db_name;")
Try
conn.open()
Msg("connection open")
catch ex as Exception
Msg(ex.message)
Finally
conn.close()
End Try
```

You can put the MySqlConnection credentials right away no need to declare it.
i hope this help's.

Comment: Please see updated Question, thanks for your answer! Looks like somethings different, getting there!

Comment: i think you should check the credentials to your server again it seems you can't access it, for more info check this [MySqlConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)